# document.cookie can't access dead object in firefox 28

Tags: javascript, firefox, cookies, firebug, dead-code

This error appeared for me for the first time today.  I'm using Firefox 28 which seems to be the most recent version.

Here is the code:  When it gets to the last line I get the error "Can't access dead object" and the page freezes, won't accept clicks anymore.  Not seeing this error in Chrome.

```
function setCookie(name, value, expiredays) {
    console.log("setting cookie to: " + name + ", value: " + value);
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + expiredays);
    var newcookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ((expiredays === null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTString());
    document.cookie = newcookie;
}
```

When I look at document.cookie in the console, it's just a string.  newcookie is a string too.  Document looks alright.

[image: dead code error]

What is this error?

Thanks for any clues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Firebug needed to update itself.  Closing Firefox entirely and restarting it presented an update tab for Firebug.  Updating firebug made this error go away.

thank you

Comment: Ah, yes, the old "Have you tried switching it off and on again."

Comment: Yes I should have realized when it was such an inexplicable bug it was something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Only thing you have missed `)` on below code,

```
...((expiredays === null) ? "" : ";expires=" + exdate.toGMTS)
                        //closeing bracket is missed--------^
```

Otherwise cookie is setting/getting to/from **Firefox 28** without any problem.

**Updated**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3S8he/2/)

Comment: Sorry, that was a cut and paste error while composing the question.  The line got chopped, but it is corrected now.  Thank you